# Maximum String Value. ODBC -> PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc

I have a SQL Server database and I connect to it with PHP, using ODBC.

I have a cell in the database that holds 3,880 characters including spaces.  When PHP query's the database it only returns the first 3,668 characters including spaces.

I've searched google and I just can't find out if this is the max length you can have, and whether you can increase it.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.addedbytes.com/blog/sql-server-php-truncating-text/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sammitch, but I'm using the ODBC driver to connect, and at the bottom of that article it says that it should work perfectly fine with ODBC.